# what kind of breaker for subpanel?

Tags: subpanel

What kind of breaker do I have to use for a sub panel of 125 amps? May I use a 125 amp breaker (same amp rating as the sub panel) from main panel to feed the sub panel?

Comment: What make and model is the subpanel? How big is the feeder wiring?

Answer (score 2):

The breaker size is decided by the wire connecting the panels.  For instance if the wire is 8 AWG, the breaker will be 40A.  Regardless of the wire size, the breaker cannot exceed 125A, presuming that is the rating of the panel.

As always, make sure you are buying a subpanel that is large enough.  It is very common for someone to save $40 on the panel, only to later have to spend a lot more than $40 for twin breakers and other work... because they got a panel that left them too little room for expansion.  Panel space is cheap.

It is totally fine to have a subpanel whose "main breaker" is *larger than* the breaker in the main panel serving it.  For instance I have a 60A circuit serving a too-small 4-space subpanel.  I replace that with a 42-space subpanel with a 225A main breaker.  That is fine.  The big main simply serves as a shutoff switch. (And I made out because the bundle came with 22 ”bonus breakers" which I use elsewhere.)